# Runtime dependencies for GAE web app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ivy, dependency-management

After downloading the GAE SDK (1.7.1) I have a *massive* amount of JARs under my `${GAE_HOME}/lib/` directory:

[image]

I am in the process of setting up a build for my GAE web app on my local machine but also plan on setting up a QA machine. I'm also using an Ivy repository hosted on a 3rd server for resolving all of my web app's dependencies.

I need to know which GAE JARs I will need to package under my web app's `WEB-INF/lib` directory, and which ones are available to my web app at runtime on both the dev appserver as well as my live/production GAE servers.

So I ask: does the production environment of GAE make all these JARs available at runtime, or do I need to package them in my WAR? And do production GAE servers make the same dependencies available as the dev appserver, or do I need to have different dependency configurations for dev and production environments? Thanks in advance!

**Please note:** I am using the Google-Eclipse plugin for a few features, but not building or uploading/deployment. I'm setting up an external Ant build that calls Ivy and other tasks that I am running from a terminal. So I'm not interested in any build-related features of the plugin!

Comment: Have you read the SDK's "README" file? I haven't needed to study it for a very long time, but this should indicate what's needed where and when.

Comment: Thanks @IanMarshall (+1) this is a good start, but is not comprehensive. The README simply tells me **not** to bundle `lib/shared` in my WAR, but to bundle `lib/user` instead. However, there are many other directories (and countless JARs) under `lib` besides `lib/shared` and `lib/user`. There's `lib/agent`, `lib/opt`, `lib/override`, etc. I'm wondering if anybody can tell me what these are, what I need them for, and when its appropriate to bundle them with my WAR or not, and there is no mention of them in the README.

Comment: I personally deploy in my war under WEB-INF/lib: 1.  All 10 jars found in lib/user;  2.  My app-specific jars: Wicket, SLF4J. I do not use the others; I do not know what they do.